# Stripe checkout modifies my db id's and then cannot proceed to delete or change stock in my db with a webhook

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments, sanity

I'm building an ecommerce with NextJs, Sanity as CMS and stripe

the problem goes when creating the checkout session stripes transforms my data from my CMS and then if I retrieve that data after succesfull with a webhook I will not be able to get the same ids of the products, I will be getting new Ids mades from stripe not my cms.

here is an example of the code when creating the session, note that I am using use-shopping-cart to handle the products cart ( validates the data after sending and also transform de array to the one that Stripes accept)

/api/route.js

```
const { validateCartItems } = require('use-shopping-cart/utilities')
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { client } from "../../../lib/sanity/client";
import { merchQuery } from "../../../lib/sanity/merchQuery";

//
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  // https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#configuration
  apiVersion: "2020-03-02",
});



export default async function handler(req, res) {


  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      // Validate the cart details that were sent from the client.
      const cartItems = req.body;

      //Sanity client performs merchQuery
      let sanityData = await client.fetch(merchQuery);

   // The POST request is then validated against the data from Sanity.
      const line_items = validateCartItems(sanityData, cartItems);


      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const params = {
        submit_type: "pay",
        mode: "payment",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        billing_address_collection: "auto",
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US"],
        },
    
      //The validated cart items are inserted.
        line_items,
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/result?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}`,
        expires_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 1800, // 
      };
      const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
   
  
      res.status(200).json(checkoutSession);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

How can I get the original ID in order to change the status of those products in the CMS.

I've been dealing with this issue for a couple of days, I can get the successufll results in the webhook api made from stripe but I onle get the "line_items" with the details transformed by stripe.

Am I thinking this the right way? or maybe there is another solution.

My flow of thinking it is

cart with products(id, details, etc) --> handlecheckout --> createSession -->> if success apply webhook from stripe that with the products ids pause or delete those products from my CMS .

i'll really appreciate some help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the Checkout Session, you could use the [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) parameter to store the original ID of the products being bought. Then when you receive the `checkout.session.completed` event, you check the `metadata` in the payload to get back the IDs and update your database accordingly.

Comment: oh man!! thanks so much, i was trying that but putting the metadata in the line_items so it never worked!,
now i just put it in the session object as you said. THANKS!!!!!!!